# 2 dimensional normal distribution

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution

Hello I have a following question: let us consider two random variables (not necessary independent) $X$, $Y$, both normally distributed. Do vector $(X,Y)$ has 2 dimensional normal distribution because linear combination of $X$ and $Y$ has normal distribution?

Comment: @flinty  covariance matrix has covariance  for off diagonal entries, not zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not the case.  Let $X \sim N(0,1)$ and $Z$ be an independent Bernoulli random variable with $P(Z=1)=P(Z=-1)=\frac 12$.  Then $Y := ZX$ is a normally distributed random variable, but $(X,Y)$ does not have a two dimensional normal distribution.  To see this, note that $P(X+Y=0) = P(Z=-1) = \frac 12$, so $X+Y$ is not normally distributed and therefore $(X,Y)$ cannot have a two dimensional normal distribution.

Comment: Okay, the formula if $X\sim N(\mu_1,\sigma^2_1)$ $Y\sim N(\mu_2,\sigma^2_2)$ then $X+Y\sim N(\mu_1+\mu_2,\sigma^2_1+\sigma^2_2)$ is only true when these random variables are independent! Now I get it... Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  There is a similar formula as long as $(X,Y)$ have a two dimensional normal distribution, but the formula for the variance is different and involves their correlation.